# Calculation of Run time

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

Given is the folowing recurrence relation:
$$ T(n) = 2 \cdot T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_2 n $$

Master theorem cannot be applied here for calculation of run time.

How can I do it instead?

Comment: It is $$T_n=c_1 2^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (4)}-1}+\frac{\sqrt{2^{\frac{2 \log (n)}{\log (4)}}}
   \log (n) \left(\frac{\log (n)}{\log (4)}+1\right)}{2
   \log (2)}$$

Comment: Hello, how do you get to that?

Comment: It was in an old note book of mine.

Comment: Ok, but how did they get to this formula?

Comment: Give me some minutes please

Comment: Yes no problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let us define $T(n)=T(4^m)=S(m)$.

Then

$$T(4^m)=2T(4^{m-1})+\sqrt{4^m}\log_2(4^m)$$

or

$$S(m)=2S(m-1)+2m2^m,$$ which is a linear recurrence.

As the characteristic equation has the root $m=2$, the solution should be of the form

$$S(m)=(am^2+mb+c)2^m$$

i.e.

$$T(n)=(a\log_4^2n+b\log_4n+c)\sqrt n.$$

(The basis of the logarithm is immaterial.)

Comment: Thank you. I get it:)